# twitter bootstrap modal in navbar opens behind mask

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the form navbar-search. I want to have an "advanced search" modal that opens from a link within the navbar.

If I put the modal div within my  tag in the navbar, when the modal opens it is *behind* the darkened area that is normally outside of the modal window. Clicking anywhere closes the modal and the darkened mask.

I can fix this by moving the modal div outside of the navbar (and, thus, outside of my form) but then it breaks my form functionality. The advanced search modal is supposed to function as an extension of the form field directly in the navbar but if I use two different forms to fix the modal problem, the forms don't work together any longer. Does that make sense?

If I enclose the entire nav bar plus my modal (which is outside the navbar) in a  tag, it works but screws up some of the navbar formatting so I'm thinking this is not a very clean solution.

So, I either need to a way to fix the modal display issue or a way to make my form situation work properly (as in, linking two forms together without having a ton of duplicate markup for hidden fields and the like).

Thanks for any ideas!
Matt

Here is what I have now (which I've gone ahead and just adjusted css afterward to make things line up). I don't think it is semantically correct according to how bootstrap's navbar is supposed to be used, but my form is working correctly and that is a big deal to me. :)

```
<form>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <modal></modal>
</form>
```

Comment: can you display more of the html. also you may want to check the z-indexes in chrome inspector or firebug and try adjusting those values and adding them to your stylesheet. It is probably possible for you to just add another class to your modal content div and set that class to have a much higher z-index than the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure what you are asking, but this is a stab at what I think you are asking. The modal does not actually need to put the code for the modal in the form itself. The only thing you need in the navbar is the link and trigger activating the modal.

```
<form>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Advanced Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Advanced Search</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Put your search fields here. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

See working link.

http://jsbin.com/ifaqaj/1/edit